# Pulling a Databricks repo into my desktop

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, repo

I created a repo in Databricks connected to the Azure DevOps git repository, and I pushed a number of notebooks to it. But when I do a "git clone" from my desktop I see the files being downloaded... but then the directory where I did the cloning from is empty (except for the .git subdirectory). I would have expected to download the notebooks as files...!?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you see files in the DevOps repo?

Comment: @AlexOtt, yes, I soo see the files in the DevOps repo

Comment: then it's something wrong with `git` itself, or something like. Maybe you're using the wrong branch?

Comment: @AlexOtt, I'm not using the wrong branch, because I see the logging in the console pulling the files. Could it be that Databricks saves the notebooks with a special format?

Comment: No, notebooks are committed as Python/Scala/R files. Here is an example of the repository with notebooks: https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring the issue a bit further, I noticed that `git clone` was warning about files with colons `:` in their names (which is not allowed in windows). After removing all the `:` the cloning worked.

I should have paid more attention to the message:

```
error: invalid path 'Tests/DatabricksExamples/ML Quickstart: Model Training.py'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
```